# Angular ng-repeat how to unwrap promise in template for each item

Tags: angularjs

In the past promises returned by a functon used to be able to be bound to a template and when the promise was resolved the value would update automatically in the template. However, I've read that this automatic unwrapping of promises no longer exists.

I've provided simplified code below to give the idea of what I am trying to do. My controller has a dataArray containing objects. Each object contains an id field. The controller has a function that takes the id and returns a promise of some data. In the template I am using an ng-repeat to loop through each object (obj) in dataArray and I want to bind to the resolved value of the promise that getData returns for each obj. However, when I do this, I get the "10 $digest() iterations reached. Aborting!" error which I've read is due to the fact that promises can no longer be bound to a template due to the lack of promise unwrapping.

Controller:

```
myApp.controller('myCtrl', function($scope, dataStore) {

  $scope.someDataArray = dataArray;  // an array of objects

  // returns a promise to provide data for the supplied id
  $scope.getData = dataStore.getData(id); 


})
```

Template:

```
<div>
  <table>
    <thead>
        ....
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <tr ng-repeat="obj in dataArray">
        <td>{{obj.item1}}</td>
        <td>{{getData(obj.id)}}</td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  <table>
<div>
```

Does anyone have a good method for passing a value from an array of values in an ng-repeat to a function that returns a promise so that when the promise resolves the value is updated in each table cell of the template?

I know that if I was doing this for a single value I could create a variable for the value on the scope and use the then() function of a promise to set the value. The template would bind to this value. However, as I am using an ng-repeat there will be separate function calls for every obj.id in dataArray.

Comment: I assume that `dataStore.getData` makes some kind of asynchronous request -- why do you want to do multiple of these?  If you have to get 100 items you will be making 100 requests when it would make more sense to get a group of 100 at a time or something.

Comment: dataStore.getData checks a local cache first and if the data is not present will do an asynchronous request to a server. Making a single call or multiple calls are both workable options.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fetch the data in your controller:

```
$scope.fetchedData = [];
$q.all($scope.someDataArray.map(function(obj) {
    return dataStore.getData(obj.id);
}).then(function(array) {
    $scope.fetchedData = array;
});
```

And in the view, display the fetched data:

```
<tr ng-repeat="obj in dataArray">
  <td>{{obj.item1}}</td>
  <td>{{ fetchedData[$index] }}</td>
</tr>
```

Answer (score 3):

Well, I personally don´t think that making that call from the view is a good practice.

I would separate things out, in the view, bind to a property that is going to be populated by the resolved promise:

```
<div>
  <table>
    <thead>
        ....
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <tr ng-repeat="obj in dataArray">
        <td>{{obj.item1}}</td>
        <td>{{obj.data)}}</td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  <table>
<div>
```

And on my controller I would make the call to getData() for every item of the array, to make it even better, I´d use a watch so every time my array gets updated I´d make sure that the calls to getData() are performed

```
myApp.controller('myCtrl', function($scope, dataStore) {

   $scope.$watch('someDataArray ', function(newArray) {
      for(var i=0; i<newArray.length; i++){
          populateData(newArray[i]);
      }
   });

   var populateData = function(obj){
      dataStore.getData(obj.id).then(function(value){
          obj.data = value;
      });
   }

   $scope.someDataArray = dataArray;  // an array of objects

});
```

I haven´t tested this out, but that´s the general idea. Hope that helps.

Comment: This won't work, when `.then()` gets invoked, `i` will always be equal to `newArray.length`.

Comment: You are absolutely right, in my rush I overlooked that, I´m gonna edit the answer to fix it